# anchor tag not redirecting to link in html

Tags: javascript, html, json, uri, anchor

I am calling an api and want to populate the uri property of api result into the html.
I am calling a function and inside it I am trying to do in this way, running the loop 3 times and want to display 3 links with uri property of every object. But this is not running as expected and directing to "datares.jsonData.data[i]" and throwing error. what am doing wrong here?

```js
let text = document.getElementById("textBody2");
for(let i =0; i< 10; i++){
text.innerHTML = "<a href= 'datares.jsonData.data[i].uri'>Linkkkk</a>";
}
```

```html
<p id="textBody2" style="text-align: center;"></p>
```

```js
{
  "jsonData": {
    "data": [
      {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "delectus aut autem",
    "uri": 'http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees'
},
     {
    "userId": 2,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "delectus aut autem",
    "uri": 'http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employee1'
},
      {
    "userId": 3,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "delectus aut autem",
    "uri": 'http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employee2'
}
    ],
    "metadata": {}
  },
  "meta": {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few things:

- `"<a href= 'datares.jsonData.data[i].uri'>Linkkkk</a>"` is a syntax error. It should be `"<a href= "+datares.jsonData.data[i].uri+">Linkkkk</a>"`.
- You are overwritting the HTML every loop cycle. Instead, use `+=`

```js
datares = {
  "jsonData": {
    "data": [{
        "userId": 1,
        "id": 1,
        "title": "delectus aut autem",
        "uri": 'http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees'
      },
      {
        "userId": 2,
        "id": 1,
        "title": "delectus aut autem",
        "uri": 'http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employee1'
      },
      {
        "userId": 3,
        "id": 1,
        "title": "delectus aut autem",
        "uri": 'http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employee2'
      }
    ],
    "metadata": {}
  },
  "meta": {}
}
let text = document.getElementById("textBody2");
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  text.innerHTML += "<a href= "+datares.jsonData.data[i].uri+">Linkkkk</a>";
}
```

```html
<p id="textBody2" style="text-align: center;"></p>
```